# Would it annoy a professor if a student does not reply their email concerning the career development of the student?

Tags: etiquette

I asked professors for recommendation letters this past year for grad school applications. I got into one school, but I’ve decided to put off going due to the coronavirus (the program was going to be online). Also, secretly, I decided I should be pursuing a different path after a lot more reflection.

All of my professors I asked for letters, understandably, told me to let them know what I end up doing. I haven’t yet. Will they be pissed off if I tell them about my change of plans? Should I just not email at all?

I do feel bad having had them write letters that ultimately will not be used.

Comment: I think you should tell them, but that it really is not important.

Comment: Professors are people and are annoyed by the same things that ordinary people are annoyed by. Try the interpersonal skills stack exchange.

Answer (score 3):

If you find a productive path then the professors will be happy to know.

They probably don’t keep a list of reference leters with “got a job” or “not got a job”... At least I don’t...

Just nice to get an email from a student from 2, 5 or more years ago with an update.